# Migrating from PHP to ASP.Net (Mono)

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, .net

I haven't seen anything on here which explicitly lists the main differences in terms of a learning curve. PHP is EXTREMELY different from the .NET world, and while I know C# fairly well, I'm not familiar with the C# methodology of server-side programming, such as making database calls via MySQL. In PHP it's easy as 1-2-3, in .NET it appears a little different than that. The positive is that the programmer tends to learn more however, I think.

Anyway, does anyone have any specific resources for those who are migrating from PHP to .NET/ASP, for C# in particular?

Comment: Even after a 9 years strong stint doing work with c#, I'd not bother switching from PHP myself.  The end game is what matters, not how you got there or the tools you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started with PHP and have taken on ASP.NET projects as well in the last few years.  Once you have a strong understanding of programming languages in general, you should have no problem adapting and figuring things out.  The biggest difference, in my opinion, is that ASP.NET has a lot of event-driven programming.  Additionally, you have to get used to ASP.NET controls in place of plain HTML.

As far as MySQL connections and various other normal server side web tasks, I doubt you will find that to be a huge learning curve once you get started.  The interaction between client side and server side is where things are different.

I'm a hands on person and learned a lot by simply starting a project.  The ASP.NET website also has many learning videos that were helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry about coming from a php background and needing something in particular. You should already have a good understanding of http request/response process. Just pick up an asp.net book, open VS, and start learning. I have a Murach's ASP.NET w/ C# book and its pretty good.. I would recommend it.

Comment: I would recommend asp.net mvc as @iamkrillin does. my answer is if you *are* looking to go to webforms

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go from PHP to ASP.Net you might look at using the ASP.NET MVC framework.  There is prob a much smaller learning curve for it coming from a php background as opposed to web forms.